# Activity backstack handling

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

Suppose I have `activities` **A, B, C, D, E**.
when I open application with activity **A** and switch to activity B and further to activity **C**. Suppose, somehow **B** gets destroyed by **system**. and when I press `back button`, I came out of app. What I really wanted was to be able to go to **B** if it exists otherwise **A** (landing page). In normal cases it's working smoothly but it's some cases where I have to interact with other **apps/interfaces** for eg. **open url in browser**. After sometime if I go back to app, I see latest page as it is but when I press back button app exits.

I have searched for solutions but couldn't find one so posting it as a question.

I know the idea of **passing extra in intent** and **starting new intent** on `back` press but these **would not work** in some cases or requires **creating a backstack handler of own**.

Comment: Did you use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods in your activities A and B?

Comment: No, I haven't . can u give some examples or idea on how to achieve the result.

Comment: IMO, even if we save instance of B, when we press back from C, B won't restore to it's previous state as its already destroyed.

Comment: make sure while moving from activity A to B and further you are **not using FINISH()** after **startInatent(i);**

Comment: nope not using finish.. as i mentioned in question it works in normal circumstances

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that your activities will stay in memory and this is an intentional behaviour.

Your option is use to `onRestoreInstanceState` and `onSaveInstanceState` so that user do not lose critical data.

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get data
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Save data        
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer... but my problem is if A->B, then how would you know A exists in memory, so that when back button is pressed from B, u can just finish B and resume A or start new A.

Comment: In `onDestroy()` method of `A`, put a shared preferences like this, `("A_destroyed", true)`. Then in `B`, check that if  `A_destroyed` is true so you can start new `A`. But this sounds absurd, I'd surrender to default behaviour of android operating system.

Answer (score 0):

One way which I have used in the past to validate activity state is to add e.g. a boolean attribute in your activity, set this true when activity starts, if your activity is destroyed after some time this will be false. Check state by overriding the activities onBackPressed method?

e.g.

```
onBackPressed(){
    if status{
        /*activity live*/
    }
    else{
        /*activity destroyed/*
    }
}
```

This might work If I understand you issue correctly.